# iCarousel issue

Tags: ios, icarousel

I'm trying to add a iCarousel to an existing project with the code below, but I'm getting this error: `MemberCatalog[14990:1a903] -[MainViewController carousel:viewForItemAtIndex:reusingView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0589b0.`

The line in iCarousel.m throwing the error is: `view = [_dataSource carousel:self viewForItemAtIndex:index reusingView:[self dequeueItemView]];`

Any help it will be really appreciate it.

```
carouselItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"iLibrary+Featured_AM-RAH.png"],
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"iLibrary+Featured_CCA.png"],
         [UIImage imageNamed:@"iLibrary+Featured_GI-PA.png"],
         nil];

// Initialize and configure the carousel
    carousel = [[iCarousel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    carousel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
carousel.delegate = self;
carousel.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:carousel];
```

---

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    UIImage *image = [carouselItems objectAtIndex:index];
    UIButton *button = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)] autorelease];
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [button.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:50];
    button.tag=index;
    return button;

}
```

Comment: Are you implementing the `-carousel:viewForItemAtIndex:reusingView:` at all??

Comment: yes. I did:- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
  UIImage *image = [carouselItems objectAtIndex:index];
 UIButton *button = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)] autorelease];
 [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 button.titleLabel.font = [button.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:50];
 button.tag=index;
 return button;
 
}

Comment: Well, that method is clearly missing the `reusingView:` part

Comment: Thank you Guys you are the best. I was implementing - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index instead of - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view

Comment: I'll post an answer so you can close this question. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're implementing a `-carousel:viewForItemAtIndex:` method, but the view expects a `-carousel:viewForItemAtIndex:reusingView:` method.

You need to update your method with the `reusingView:(UIView *)view` parameter and you'll be fine. You should also use that reusable view instead of allocating more and more views, but that's another story.